# The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I just setup an Exchange 2013 server hosted on the same machine as the Active Domain Controller.

I tested the connectivity of the server , I found that the mailbox can only send email to external mailbox however it can't receive any mail either from external mail or internal mail.

I ran the Exchange connectivity analyzer for inbound mail and it failed with the following message.

> The server returned status code 451 - Error in processing. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3

I did a search on technet forum and found the following thread

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/288e1619-ce56-4c3a-8bb1-4886835520fe/delivery-fails-the-server-response-was-470-temporary-server-error-please-try-again-later?forum=exchangesvrdeploy

but no luck , i dont know how to set an alternative host, would somebody please help.

error details:

```
Message: Error in processing. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3 
Type: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
Stack trace:
at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String serverResponse)
at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Tools.ExRca.Tests.SmtpMessageTest.PerformTestReally() 

The server returned status code 451 - Error in processing. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3 
Exception details:
Message: Error in processing. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3 
Type: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
Stack trace:
at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String serverResponse)
at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Tools.ExRca.Tests.SmtpMessageTest.PerformTestReally()
Elapsed Time: 3107 ms.
The server returned status code 451 - Error in processing. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3 
Exception details:
Message: Error in processing. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3 
Type: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
Stack trace:
at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String serverResponse)
at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Tools.ExRca.Tests.SmtpMessageTest.PerformTestReally()
Elapsed Time: 3107 ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, send and recieving of emails is the function of Hub Transport services. in your case, you installed MS Exchange 2013 on a domain controller that is not a recommended practice. try to install MS Exchange 2013 on a separate member server not on a DC. Moreover, if its a test environment then open services snap-in and choose "Active Directory Topology Service" open its property page and on Log-on page select Admin user with password from AD and  that user must have following security group memberships

1. Enterprise Admin
2. Schema Admin
3. Organization Management
4. Domain Admin

and restart the service that shall result in all exchange server services to be restarted automatically. if you feel any problem in restarting the services then simply restart your machine.

do let me know if it helps :)

Regards,

Adnan.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your servers hosts file (c:\windows\system32\Drivers\etc)
(replace servername, domain and IP with your servers)

192.168.1.5 servername
192.168.1.5 servername.domain.local

Restart Microsoft Exchange Transport and Microsoft Exchange Frontend Transport services

source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/fc26dac5-d4e2-49da-903d-361ea8b85388/451-470-temporary-server-error-please-try-again-later-prx5?forum=exchangesvrgeneral

Answer (score 0):

DNS issue.
Similar to your Exchange 2013 setup where DNS setup MUST only contain one IP address in the list of primary and backup DNS servers (for some reason unknown, providing MORE than one address in the Exchange config for DNS confuses the crap out of Exchange 2013) providing MORE than one IP address in the NIC card, (IV4 in my case) settings for DNS causes Exchange 2013 confusion when attempt to DNS the DC name.

Eliminating one of (the two DNS server IP addresses I had specified) IP criteria for the ONE active NIC card, resulting in ONLY one IP address on the server solved my exchange errors:
"The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3 Type: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException"

Like others in this thread, the failures were intermittent.  The number seems to be 1/3 failures, 2/3 success, which makes for a very frustrating analysis as you make a change, the messages begin to flow and you think you have solved the issue, only to have the issue manifest again 1 hour later :(

Answer (score 0):

A bit of searching revealed the answer:

In my home lab environment I currently only have 1 domain controller, so naturally, I put my router as my secondary DNS server on all my configurations.

This results in the above error message. I simply removed the secondary DNS which does not point to my internal DNS/Domain Controller and now I am able to receive an email.

Forwarding typically would be handled by the DNS servers in your environment, so a secondary public DNS would not be configured in a typical production environment. In a home Lab potentially you might run into this problem.

[Source](https://gerhardwessels.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/451-4-7-0-temporary-server-error-please-try-again-later-prx2/)